# making a gallery with asynctask but it is slow

Tags: android, android-asynctask, image-gallery

I am making a photo gallery for my app , and I'm using `asynctask` for loading images from storage into `Image View` , but It's performance is not good!
It is very slow indeed!(also I can't use libraries like `glide` and `universal image loader`)
is there any other way for making this gallery faster? I have searched a lot but I'm confused with all the solutions.
here is my `getview` function in `grid view adapter` :

```
  @Override
        public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");

            file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());

            ImageView imageView;

                if (convertView == null) {

                    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);


                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));

                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                } else {

                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                }

                new myTask(imageView, file).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

            return imageView;
            }
```

and here is my `asynctask` class:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask <Void , Void ,Bitmap> {
    ImageView iv;
    File file;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public myTask(ImageView iv, File file) {
        this.iv=iv;
        this.file= file;
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 16;
        final int THUMBSIZE = 64;
        Bitmap bmp = null;



        try {
            bmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options),
                    THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmp;
     }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap aVoid) {

        iv.setImageBitmap(aVoid);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know what is  problem in using Glide, but from Offical web Android is recommending glide [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I am using a virtual file system called IOCipher, I tried using glide but it could not load images , the problem of my previous question!

Comment: In that case, move the file into some temp folder which you can create in sdcard, and store the decrypted image and load from there, Once the user goes out of the app, just delete the complete the file.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran but it seems to be a little unsafe , its important for me to keep the safety of my app :(

Comment: You can make it safe by handling your Activity life cycle correctly.

Comment: You could use [Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#InternalCache) to save file and this will remain private to your application. So this will be safe too.